# XML Sitemap upload for Wordpress site

Tags: seo, wordpress, sitemap, xml

I had previously used an XML Sitemap auto generator on the AIOSEO plugin but wanted to make some changes to the prioritization of some of the URLs that I could not change through the functions of the plugin, I downloaded the XML Sitemap by going to the /sitemap.xml url and right clicking and saving, opened it with Sublime and changed the priorities and re-saved it as an XML Document.

Then I turned off the auto generated sitemap and uploaded the recently saved altered sitemap with the file name sitemap.xml via FTP the the root directory of the site, this was all I thought I needed to do but upon returning to the /sitemap.xml url it brings me to my sites 404 message.

Any ideas as to why it is not working? Or have I uploaded it incorrectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly remove all in one SEO plugin from your WordPress dashboard, Now upload the new one on the Root & Submit your updated sitemap.xml file into Google Webmaster.
You All Done.

Comment: Managed to get it to work after deactivating AIOSEO, thanks!